# How to transfer the formatted date string from my DatePickerFragment?

Tags: android, android-datepicker

Following the official doc http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker.

I have used just the same code, and added only the result formatting in the `onDateSet` method:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());

        // How to get the string from here to the caller?

    }
}
```

For testing, the caller activity just displays the `TextView` and calls the picker when the user touches the widget:

```
public class OrderHeadEditActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mDTDelivery;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        ...
        mDTDelivery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order_head_view_dt_delivery);
        ...
        mDTDelivery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
                picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });
    }
...
}
```

The date picker is displayed, and after setting the breakpoint at the place where the result is formatted to a string, I can see it works.

However, I do not know how to pass the string value back to the `mtDTDelivery` widget?

Comment: make your datapicker class an inner class of your activity class

Comment: have you tried the below??. the interface method will work.

Comment: I did not try, yet. I will try later today. I would like to understand it first. (I am new to Java and its iterfaces, and also new to Android.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As tyczj pointed out you can use the interface method or you could make datapicker class an inner class of your activity class in which case it should be static and you need a weakreference of the outerclass

Using interface.

Define a interface in `DatePickerFragment`. Implement the interface in your activity class and set the date to textview.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    TheListener listener;

public interface TheListener{
    public void returnDate(String date);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
listener = (TheListener) getActivity(); 

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, day);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
if (listener != null) 
{
  listener.returnDate(formattedDate); 

}

}
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DatePickerFragment.TheListener{

    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
                picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void returnDate(String date) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv.setText(date);
    }

}
```

Second way not sure if this is the best way. I would recommend the above interface method.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {//implements DatePickerFragment.TheListener{

    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
                picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        private WeakReference<MainActivity> mActivity;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mActivity = new WeakReference<MainActivity>((MainActivity) getActivity());

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year, month, day);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
      MainActivity target = mActivity.get(); 
      if (target != null) target.tv.setText(formattedDate);

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to study it a bit more. Anyway, how it happens the `listener` in the `DatePickerFragment` gets its non-null value?

Comment: you define a interface in `DatePickerFragment`. Then implement the interface in your activity class. You set the value to the interface method. Since your activity class implements the interface you get the value there. Check the topic **Creating event callbacks to the activity** http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: @pepr to know about interface. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: Thanks, it works. I did not noticed earlier the line `listener = (TheListener) getActivity();` :) Thanks also for the links.

Comment: @pepr glad i could help. `getActivity()` will get you the activity context of the hosting activity. remember fragment is hosted by a activity.

Comment: It's clear now. The overlooked line was the answer to my first comment here ;)

Comment: How to use for multiple buttons in one Fragment @Raghunandan

Comment: @Raghunandan When I add this line `listener = (TheListener) getActivity();` and I click on the EditTextBox the App stop Working and get closed automaticly

Comment: @pepr can you help me in my post over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718067/get-selected-date-from-datepickerfragment/26718287

Comment: In Oncick write this 

 DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment (new SelectDateFragment.TheListener() {
            @Override
            public void returnDate(String date) {
                dateOfBirth.setText(date);
                dobValue = date;
            }
        });
        picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");


And in Date DatePickerFragment  add a constructor :  public DatePickerFragment (TheListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

Comment: @Chlebta check my above answer

Comment: @SagarDevanga no need for that. You just need the activity to implement the interface.

Comment: mine crashed too when i wrote this listener = (TheListener) getActivity(); 
So i figured out a work around.Anyways thanx

Comment: You need to check why it crashed. But if ur activity implements the interface it will work fine. You can check the same in the docs fragment to fragment communication

Comment: @Raghunandan: Could you elaborate on the "static nested class + weak reference" approach you mention at the beginning of your post? More specifically, what exactly do you mean by "weak reference"? The only option I see would consist in using `getActivity()` to get a reference to the original activity and notify it of any changes.

Comment: Look at the second answer posted in the post. Also read about static and weak reference along with memory leaks due to context

Answer (score 4):

The proper way is to create a callback to the activity passing the string.

take a look at [Communicating with an Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)