# How to validate date in dd/mm/yyyy format in editext in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two edittexts. I want to validate date entered in first edittext when I switch to next edittext... Is it possible?
I want to validate in dd/mm/yyyy format strictly..
please help me..
i searched and tried also but not get such a solution..

Comment: what effort you put for this? tell more about your date format

Comment: Better to use [DatepickerDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267091/open-a-datepickerdialog-on-click-of-edittext-and-set-the-date-value-android) instead of Edittext for date inputs..'

Comment: only after api 21 it is ok to call the Calendar class...

Answer (score 1):

## Step 1

```
       youredittextname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Is_Valid_date(name); // pass your EditText Obj here.
            }
        });
```

## Step 2

Write a function.

```
       public void Is_Valid_date(EditText edt) throws NumberFormatException {
        if (edt.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
            edt.setError("Accept number Only.");
            valid_name = null;
        } else if (check your date format using simpledate format) {
            edt.setError("Accept Alphabets Only.");
            valid_name = null;
        } else {
            valid_name = edt.getText().toString();
        }

    }
```

If you need to know Validate of the date.
Please visit this link.

### http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-date-with-regular-expression/

Thank you.

Comment: thank you sethu.. Can You tell me how to check date format using simpledate format.. please sir

Comment: refer below link boss you will get it. study simple date format.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416595/date-validation-in-android

Comment: sir I resolved it... Thank You so much.. your post helped me alot.. thank you once again...

Comment: boss no sir and all okay. you are the most welcome person. all the best do well.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static  final String  DATE_PATTERN="(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\\d\\d)";
private Pattern pattern= Pattern.compile(DATE_PATTERN);
    

   public boolean isValidDate(final String date) {

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(date);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            matcher.reset();
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String day = matcher.group(1);
                String month = matcher.group(2);
                int year = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
                if (date.equals("31") && (month.equals("4")
                        || month.equals("6")
                        || month.equals("9")
                        || month.equals("11")
                        || month.equals("04")
                        || month.equals("06")
                        || month.equals("09"))) {
                    return false;
                } else if (month.equals("2") || month.equals("02")) {
                    if (year % 4 == 0) {
                        if (day.equals("30") || day.equals("31")) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (day.equals("29") || day.equals("30") || day.equals("31")) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use interface `TextWatcher` in Android. You have to override its methods:

- In `onTextChanged()` limit the length of text
- In `afterTextChanged()` use some good regular expression for date validation. It will be available from Google.

Answer (score -1):

SimpleDateFormat can be of your help. You can look for tutorials or else visit [here](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/)