# Check if TextView is empty?

Tags: java, android, date, textview

I am displaying a date in a [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView). It is all working fine when there is some date. But if no date is chosen or if the [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) is empty (there is a hint "dd-mm-yyyy" though) then the app crashes. I am checking for empty [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) as follows: `if(textview.setText().toString().isEmpty()) {//show error}` can anyone help what I am doing wrong?

Initialisation of [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) and [`TextInputlayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout):

```
tv_Current_Date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Current_Date);
til_Current_Date = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.til_Current_Date);
```

Here is the code responsible for crash:

```
if (tv_Current_Date.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    til_Current_Date.setError("Please choose a date");
}
```

Method to set date:

```
public void setCurrentDateOnView() {
    String dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.US);
    tv_Current_Date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Current_Date);
    tv_Current_Date.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar_now.getTime()));
    String short_weekday = new DateFormatSymbols().getShortWeekdays()[day_of_current_week];
    tv_Current_weekday.setText(short_weekday);
}
```

Comment: Also add the part where you define til_Current_Date in case it is there you are having the problem.

Comment: what crash are you received?

Comment: I have editted my code, @Juan. The app was getting stopped-an_droid_dev.

Comment: Sorry guys, actually I initialised the TextView inside the setCurrentDateOnView() method locally, but I had to initialise it globally. My code is working fine now. Thank you @Juan for pointing to my mistake.

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
if (tv_Current_Date.getText().toString().equals("")) {
      til_Current_Date.setError("Please choose a date");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation. Actually the problem was to initialize the TextView. Now I have corrected it, and my code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(tv_Current_Date.getText().toString().equals("") && tv_Current_Date.getText().length() <= 0){
   tv_Current_Date.setError("your message");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation. Actually the problem was to initialize the TextView. Now I have corrected it, and my code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what Tejas and joao86 said, you should check and validate that the input is actually a date.

Check the following links where they discuss about validation:

[Date Validation in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416595/date-validation-in-android)

[How to validate date in dd/mm/yyyy format in editext in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659908/how-to-validate-date-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-editext-in-android)

[Java: Check the date format of current string is according to required format or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231539/java-check-the-date-format-of-current-string-is-according-to-required-format-or)

Answer (score 0):

You need an else condition besides an if condition to run your code.

```
if (tv_Current_Date.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                til_Current_Date.setError("Please choose a date");
            } else{ put the code here}
```