# How to get TimePickerDialog on edittext appears at first click

Tags: android, android-timepicker

How to get TimePickerDialog on edittext appears at first click? It takes twice click to get the dialog appears (the first click shows keyboard). 
Gradle : *minSdkVersion 9* and *targetSdkVersion 23*

Layout :

```
<EditText
         android:id="@+id/txtTime"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1">
         <requestFocus></requestFocus>

      </EditText>
```

Component :

```
txtTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {


            // Process to get Current Time
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(Pulse7DatePickerDialogActivity.this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                         int minute) {
                      // Display Selected time in textbox
                      txtTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                   }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            tpd.show();

         }
      });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a DatePickerDialog on Click of EditText takes two clicks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267091/open-a-datepickerdialog-on-click-of-edittext-takes-two-clicks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in layout declaration

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/txtTime"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
     android:layout_weight="1">         

  </EditText>
```