# How can I transfer data from one fragment to another fragment android

Tags: android, fragment

One way I know that is through activity.We can send data from fragment to activity and activity to fragment Is there any other way.

Comment: use a interface communicate with the hosting activity an then transfer data t the fragment from activity

Comment: ^ no, don't do that..
see this..
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733304/callback-to-a-fragment-from-a-dialogfragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733304/callback-to-a-fragment-from-a-dialogfragment)

Comment: look at my edit..
oh well, again i misunderstood question..
@skybolt, you can use Bundle to do that.. it's for passing data

Comment: @Zyoo look at my post straight from the docs

Comment: yes, i thought the question was for dialogfragment callback..

Comment: @Zyoo question does not mention `DialogFragment` any where and even if it is why would that be a problem??

Comment: yes yes, it's my brain making problems.. AFAIK, the dialogfragment could be destroyed, then your listener would be null, so for example, on dialog button click, i use [getTargetFragment()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getTargetFragment())

Comment: @Zyoo i have used interface with a datepicker fragment which extends DialogFragment and i haven't faced any issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211684/how-to-transfer-the-formatted-date-string-from-my-datepickerfragment

Comment: yes, but using `getTargetFragment()` is recommended in link above and here too (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905312/receive-result-from-dialogfragment) .. maybe your `DialogFragment` is retained or somewhat..

Answer (score 15):

To pass data from one fragment to another `Bundle` will help.

```
LifeShapeDetailsFragment fragment = new LifeShapeDetailsFragment(); //  object of next fragment
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("position", id);
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then `push/call next Fragments.`

and code to next Fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
int myInt = bundle.getInt("position", 0);
```

Comment: According to original android developers document, this approach is wrong. We should use activity to communicate between two fragments. Here is the link : http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from the docs

Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. **All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.**

I suggest you follow the method in the docs and i haven't tried any other alternative

For more info and example chekc the docs in the below link

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: what if i'm using `setRetainInstance(true)`? does it still need to pass to the activity first?

Comment: yes. check the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)

Answer (score 4):

There are two methods I'd consider viable:

**A**.Communicate with your owning activity and forward messages to other fragments via that owning activity, details on that can be found int he official android documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

**Quote:**

> In some cases, you might need a fragment to share events with the
>   activity. A good way to do that is to define a callback interface
>   inside the fragment and require that the host activity implement it.
>   When the activity receives a callback through the interface, it can
>   share the information with other fragments in the layout as necessary.

The Communication interface could look something like this:

```
public interface IActionListener{

  //You can also add parameters to pass along etc
  public void doSomething();
}
```

The fragment would look something like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

private WeakReference<IActionListener> actionCallback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
            // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
            actionCallback = new WeakReference<IActionListener>((IActionListener) activity);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement IActionListener.");
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a WeakReference here but that's really up to you. You can now use actionCallback to communicate with the owning activity and call the methods defined in IActionListener.

The owning Activity would look like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements IActionListener {

public void doSomething(){ //Here you can forward information to other fragments }

}
```

**B**. Now as for the **second method** - you can have fragments directly communicate with each other using interfaces as well - this way you don't have to know the exact class of the fragment you are talking to, which ensures loose coupling.

The setup is as follows: You have two fragments (or more) and an activity (to start the second fragment). We have an interface that lets Fragment 2 send a response to Fragment 1 once it has completed it's task. For the sake of simplicity we just re-use the interface I defined in **A.**

Here is our Fragment 1 :

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements IActionListener {

 public void doSomething() {//The response from Fragment 2 will be processed here}

}
```

Using the method described in A. Fragment 1 asks it's owning Activity to start Fragment 2. However, the Activity will pass along Fragment 1 as an argument to Fragment 2, so Fragment 2 can later indirectly access Fragment 1 and send the reply. Let's look at how the Activity preps Fragment 2:

```
    public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // The number is pretty random, we just need a request code to identify our request later
    public final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;
    //We use this to identify a fragment by tag
    public final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "MyFragmentTag";

        @Override
        public void onStartFragmentTwo() {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

                    // The requesting fragment (you must have originally added Fragment 1 using 
                    //this Tag !)
            Fragment requester = manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);   
                    // Prepare the target fragment
            Fragment target = new FragmentTwo();
                    //Here we set the Fragment 1 as the target fragment of Fragment 2's       
                    //communication endeavors
            target.getSelf().setTargetFragment(requester, REQUEST_CODE);

                    // Hide the requesting fragment, so we can go fullscreen on the target
            transaction.hide(requester);
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, target.getSelf(), FRAGMENT_TAG);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

**Hint**: I am using the Support-Framework, so if you develop solely for > Android 3.0 you can simply use FragmentActivity instead of ActionBarActivity.

Now FragmentTwo is being started, let's look at how FragmentTwo would communicate with FragmentOne:

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            // Restore our target fragment that we previously saved in onSaveInstanceState
            setTargetFragment(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, TAG),
                    MyActivity.REQUEST_CODE);           
        }

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // Retain our callback fragment, the TAG is just a key by which we later access the fragment
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, TAG, getTargetFragment());
    }

    public void onSave(){
        //This gets called, when the fragment has done all its work and is ready to send the reply to Fragment 1
        IActionListener callback = (IActionListener) getTargetFragment();
        callback.doSomething();
    }

}
```

Now the implementation of doSomething() in Fragment 1 will be called.

Comment: I think there is a code error in your very first code excerpt. You call your WeakReference "ActionListener" at one point and "ActionCallback" at another. Can you please check this?

Comment: @ParthShah oh thanks! Wrote this off the top of my head and failed to double-check variable names - thank you again, I corrected it

Comment: Nevertheless, the answer is excellent with lots of a great examples! Great job!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution,

Follow below steps:

1 create the interface like that

```
     public interface TitleChangeListener
      {
       public void onUpdateTitle(String title);
      }
```

2.implements your activity using this interface

```
    for.e.g 
    public class OrderDetail extends ActionBarActivity  implements TitleChangeListener
```

3.in this activity create on onUpdateTitle()

```
        public void onUpdateTitle(String title)
        {
         //here orderCompletedDetail is the object second fragment name ,In which fragement I want send data.

         orderCompletedDetail.setTitle(title);
         }
```

4.Now, In Fragment one write some code.

```
          public class OrderPendingDetail extends Fragment
          {
          private View rootView;
          private Context context;
          private OrderDetail orderDetail;
          @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,    Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
             rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_pending_detail, container, false);
            context = rootView.getContext();

            //here OrderDetail is the name of ActionBarActivity 
            orderDetail = (OrderDetail) context;

         //here pass some text to second Fragment using button ClickListener
           but_updateOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
               {
                // here call to Activity onUpdateTitle()
                orderDetail.onUpdateTitle("bridal");
                }
        });
        return rootView;
         }
         }
```

5.write some code in second Fragment setTitle()

```
            public void setTitle(String title)
             {
             TextView orderCompeted_name=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_orderCompeted_name);
             orderCompeted_name.setText(title);
             //here you see the "bridal" value for TextView
             }
```

In this solution when you click on button of Fragment one that time it shows  value in second Fragment .
I hope it will be helpful for you..!!

Answer (score 0):

Allowing fragments to communicate with each other by using activities as their intermediaries is a common best practice when using fragments. Visit http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html for more details on this important pattern. Anytime you need to interact with another fragment, you should always use a method in the fragment’s activity rather than
access the other fragment directly. The only time it makes sense to access one fragment from another is when you know that you won’t need to reuse your fragment in another activity. You should almost always write fragments assuming that you’ll reuse them rather than hard-code them to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM, then you can use **Shared ViewModel**,
Another option is **Fragment Result API**

Please see the following doc for more details

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate