# How to make callBack response from one fragment to another fragment?

Tags: android

Sir/Madam,
I want to make a callback result to one fragment to another fragment using android JAVA.
I try-out to find the issue but non of the solution found.
If i using interface it send callback response to Activity, which i didn't want.
thank you!

Comment: Can you share the code you tried to make the callback?

Comment: @Zulqarnain. I have tried using interfaces which return callback to activity.

Comment: follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24382033/6825339

Answer (score 1):

You have many options to do so:

1. Shared ViewModel (Recommended) (https://medium.com/@abhilashmyworld/communicate-between-fragments-using-viewmodel-e83344e9df53)
2. EventBus
3. Through the Hosting activity (calling method on fragment object)
4. Passing objects
5. Broadcast (too old school)