# How do I make a previously selected date in DatePickerFragment dialog be the default on edit?

Tags: android, date, android-datepicker

I have a DatePickerFragment that launches a dialog for the user to select a date.  The dialog uses today's date as the default date.  Once the user selects a date the code updates an EditText line in the layout.  If the user later goes back to the EditText line to edit the date, I want the dialog to the previously selected date, not the default date which is today's date.   I read that onPrepareDialog() is deprecated so don't want to use that.  I basically need to store the year, month and day that the user initially sets and then use those later rather than today's date when the dialog shows a second time.

```
partial Fragment file:
...
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

private EditText txtDate;
private Calendar cal;
private int currentyear;
private int currentmonth;
private int currentday;
private String stringDueDateFrag;

public DatePickerFragment() {
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Use the current date as the default date that we get from a Calendar object, in the DatePicker Dialog.
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    currentmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    currentday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,currentyear,currentmonth,currentday);

    return dialog;
}


    txtDate = (EditText) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().findViewById(R.id.FEditText);
    stringDueDateFrag = (month + 1) + "/" + day + "/" + year + " ";
    txtDate.setText(stringDueDateFrag);
    txtDate.setSelection(txtDate.getText().length());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `onCreate()` method you initialize the current date every time, you should pass the date from `EditText` to the `DialogFragment` everytime you calls it.

Similar question for references

[Set date of datepickerdialog from EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908805/set-date-of-datepickerdialog-from-edittext)

Comment: So set up a Calendar object and a Bundle with the EditText date and then call the Bundle the next time the EditText is seleted?

Comment: Send the EditText date as bundle, receive the bundle at dialog fragement, convert the EditText date to date format and set it as current date, display dialog

Comment: Ok and all of that is set up outside of OnCreate correct?