# date picker with fragment class android

Tags: android, datepicker

i am developing an application with the navigation drawer. when i click some items in the navigation list it shows some interface using a fragment. and my click items also working properly. i have use an image button to show a date picker. i have use below codes. but when i set an date from data picker dialog. it does not change the given text view. please guide me with some code samples..

```
public class FindPeopleFragment extends DialogFragment  implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener  {

    public int year;
    public int month;
    public int day;
    static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111; 
    TextView curentDate;




public FindPeopleFragment(TextView date){
    curentDate = date;
}
public FindPeopleFragment(){

}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule, container, false);
    ImageButton date = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnDate); 
     curentDate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentDate);

     /*final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    curentDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
    // Month is 0 based, just add 1
    .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
    .append(year).append(" "));*/


    date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);
            showDatePickerDialog(v);
        }
    });
    return rootView;


}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), datePickerListener, year, month, day);

}
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int syear, int smonth, int sday) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    month = smonth;
    day = sday;
    year = syear;
    curentDate.setText(String.valueOf(month + 1 ) + "/" +   String.valueOf(day) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));

}

};

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a constructor with params is a bad idea.

Use a interface as a call back to the activity and set the date selected to textview in activity or framgent.

From DialogFragment to Activity

[How to transfer the formatted date string from my DatePickerFragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211684/how-to-transfer-the-formatted-date-string-from-my-datepickerfragment)

Activity to Fragment

[Send data from activity to fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

DialogFragment-->Activity-->Fragment

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: hi i am not using activity here. when the user press an item on navigation list it is only show this fragment class. how can i do this with only the fragment without activity

Comment: @GishanthaDarshana you can't have a fragment without activity. Fragment is hosted by a activity. SO communicate date to activity. then activity to fragment. MainActivity is the one that hosts the framgents. You will have a container you just add or replace framgents.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that.. i have no idea with fragments an all.. what i understood is fragment class inflate my layout. and i can handle click events in the fragment. i have done certain things in one fragment. it has a button , when it is pressed it calls some web service and do some tasks. can you explain more further please

Comment: @GishanthaDarshana the docs has a example. read it first and check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211684/how-to-transfer-the-formatted-date-string-from-my-datepickerfragment

Comment: yes sir... i have searched it everywhere and finally it works. and your guidence also helpful thank you so much... sorry for the delay .